# Requiring at least 2 check boxes be clicked using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, checkbox, required

I am trying to build a form that requires at least two check boxes to be selected. I have tried everything that I could find without any sort of success.

```js
function cb_require() {
  let chckbx = document.forms['form_name']['contact'].value;

  for (chckbx.length === 1) {
    if (i = 0; i < chckbx.length; i++) {
      alert('check 2');
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="post" name="form_name" id="form_name" action="mailto:bb@yahoo.com" enctype="text/plain" onsubmit="return cb_require()">
  <label for="cont">Preferred Contact Method:</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="Phone" name="contact" value="Phone">
  <label for="Phone">Phone</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="E-mail" name="contact" value="E-email">
  <label for="E-mail">E-mail</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="Mail" name="contact" value="Mail">
  <label for="Mail">Mail</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="LinkedIn" name="contact" value="LinkedIn">
  <label for="LinkedIn">LinkedIn</label><br><br>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance for any help or advice!

Answer (score 1):

You can simple use `querySelectorAll` for filter only `checkbox checked`, if `length` is equal to two `submit` form like:

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#form_name');
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let chckboxs = form.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
  if (chckboxs.length > 1) {
    console.log('form submit');
  } else {
    console.log('error form');
  }
});
```

```html
<form method="post" name="form_name" id="form_name" action="mailto:bb@yahoo.com" enctype="text/plain">
  <label for="cont">Preferred Contact Method:</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="Phone" name="contact" value="Phone">
  <label for="Phone">Phone</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="E-mail" name="contact" value="E-email">
  <label for="E-mail">E-mail</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="Mail" name="contact" value="Mail">
  <label for="Mail">Mail</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="LinkedIn" name="contact" value="LinkedIn">
  <label for="LinkedIn">LinkedIn</label><br><br>
  <button type="submit">ClickMe</button>
</form>
```

Reference:

- [*.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: thank you for the help. I had to change the console.log() to alert(), this shows the function is working. However, it will not actually send the form via the mailto: attribute in the form tag of the HTML, when submitted. Is there a way to correct this issue?

Comment: My was just an example, you just need to send it manually like `form.submit();`

Comment: Have you test my code?